# Why after defining a toString function a comparison between objects returns false?

Tags: javascript, null, comparison

**Can anyone explain that behavior?**

Is there a different treatment for `toString` which returns `null` value?

```js
let o1 = {
  toString: function () {
    return 1;
  }
};
console.log(o1 == 1); // returns true
console.log(o1.toString() == 1); // returns true

const o2 = {
  toString: function () {
    return null;
  }
};
console.log(o2 == null); // Why this comparison returns false?
console.log(o2.toString() == null); // returns true
```

**Happy coding and thanks in advance!**

Comment: you're not overriding anything like that. toString belongs to the prototype.

Comment: o2 == null returns false because o2 is an object and o2.toString() == null is true because your function returns true

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. thank you for your comment.  Why false?

Comment: `toString` only gets called by `==` if type coersion is necessary. Since both operands are objects, there's no need to call `toString`, and it compares references.

Comment: @4castle can you share with me any documentation about what you've stated?  Thanks!!

Comment: That is why [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) exists. Use `===` and you will get expected results..

Comment: @4castle `typeof null` might be "object", but they aren't really of the same type. `o2` is of type `Object` and `null` is of type `Null`. They still don't get coerced. The algorithm for `==` simply exits at the last step and returns false.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 You're right, the specification says it must return false, so I'm only guessing at how it might be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how the [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) works.

The first thing you need to know is `typeof null` is "object", however there is also the [`Null Type`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.2)

The first check of the algorithm is

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then

Now, we have `o2` on the left hand and `null` on the right hand.

`Type(o2)` is the `Object Type` and `Type(null)` is the `Null Type`

There follows a list of 9 conditions, neither of which apply and the algorithm ends with the last step.

> 10. Return false

That means, your `toString` function never actually get's called and your object never get's coerced into a primitive.

You can verify that by doing

```
var o = {
  toString () {
    console.log ("toString")
    return null;
  }, 
  valueOf () {
    console.log ("valueOf")
    return null
  }
}
o == null
```

Nothing get's logged.

If you try to compare them using the `>=` and `<=` operators, your object get's coerced.

```
o2 <= null && o2 >= null //true
```

---

Here is the full algorithm

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>      a. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
>      b. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>      c. If Type(x) is Number, then
>         i. If x is NaN, return false.
>         ii. If y is NaN, return false.
>         iii. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>         iv. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>         v. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>         vi. Return false.
>      d. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same
>      sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding
>      positions). Otherwise, return false.
>      e. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.
>      f. Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return  false.
> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String,
>      return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number,
>      return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
> 8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object,
>      return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
> 9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number,
>      return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
> 10. Return false.

Comment: thank you for sharing.  This will help the community to understand a little more the JavaScript language.